# Calculating $\lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\Delta x(\sin (\Delta y) -\Delta y)}{\sqrt{((\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2})^3} $

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to calculate $$\displaystyle\lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\Delta x(\sin (\Delta y) -\Delta y)}{\sqrt{((\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2})^3} $$ to tell if the following function is differentiable at $(0,0)$: $f(x,y)=\frac{x(\sin y-y)}{x^2+y^2} $ is $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, else $0$.
I was trying to determine this using the definition of differentiability $f(x_0+\Delta x, y_0+\Delta y)-f(x_0,y_0)=f_x(x_0,y_0)\Delta x +f_y(x_0,y_0)\Delta y +\epsilon\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2} $ where $\epsilon(\Delta x,\Delta y)\to 0$ when $\Delta x,\Delta y\to 0$.

I would be happy to hear your thoughts. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{x(\sin (x-y))}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}=\frac{\sin (x-y)}{x-y}\frac{x(x-y)}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}\to 0$$

indeed

$$\frac{\sin (x-y)}{x-y}\to 1$$

and

$$\frac{x(x-y)}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}=\frac{\rho^2(\cos^2 \theta-\sin \theta\cos \theta)}{\rho\sqrt{\rho}}=\sqrt{\rho}(\cos^2 \theta-\sin \theta\cos \theta)\to 0$$

Comment: I upvoted the answer because the steps look good. Maybe I would just avoid to mix Cartesian and polar coordinates.

Comment: @Gibbs Yes it is only for use a short way, I fix it better! Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much! that looks nice.

Comment: @NoyPerel Sorry I've made a few of mess up to fix after the observation by Gibbs, now it should be ok!

Comment: one more thing, it should be $x\sin(y)-xy$ in the nominator though, according to the limit I referred to... but still in regards to a different  problem, that's nice :)

Comment: @NoyPerel It is the same problem. Note that in the first line we separate the two parts and since $\frac{\sin (x-y)}{x-y}\to 1$ we can study the simpler $\frac{x(x-y)}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}$ and show that its limit is $0$.